# unable to get remote addr request.META ['REMOTE_ADDR'] not working

Tags: django, django-views

hi 
i am unable to get  ip address of the user connecting to my site under django 1.1.1.

```
ip_address=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

em using python 2.6 django 1.1.1 under ubuntu 10.10

i have also installed the middle ware and tried this method also

```
'django.middleware.http.SetRemoteAddrFromForwardedFor'



try:
   ip_address=request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
except KeyError:
    pass
else:
    # HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR can be a comma-separated list of IPs.
    # Take just the first one.
    ip_address = ip_address.split(",")[0]
    request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] = ip_address
```

and in the templates i also tried to get IP using  `{{ request.REMOTE_ADDR }}`
but unable to get the  IP 
what will be the reason for this 
any help wil be greatly appreaciated thanks

Comment: is there a way to check this thing in python shell. to verify that if actually i am getting an ip address or not under django development server

Comment: it works with my version 1.2.3, why don't you try a django update

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem is solved 
i dont know what was the issue but re installation
of django solved solved the problem